# Creating Multiple SetParameters.xml from One Build task

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am searching for a solution that allows me to generate a Web Deploy Package and the associated deploy.cmd and SetParameters.xml.

But I need to generate a deploy.cmd and SetParameters.xml Per Environment

I would need my output to look like the following

- ProjectName.DevSetParameters.xml
- ProjectName.DevDeploy.cmd
- ProjectName.UATSetParameters.xml
- ProjectName.UATDeploy.cmd
- ProjectName.PRODSetParameters.xml
- ProjectName.PRODDeploy.cmd
- ProjectName.zip

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi's blog and web package nuget extension he created.
NuGet package that extends the web packaging process in Visual Studio to enable you to create a single package which can be published to multiple environments

[Package once publish anywhere](http://sedodream.com/2011/12/24/PackageOncePublishAnywhere.aspx) - you will need to look at the powershell script it creates and call it from your build task with the appropriate values.

[image: Nuget install from VS command line]
[SAYED IBRAHIM HASHIMI Blog](http://sedodream.com/2012/03/14/PackageWebUpdatedAndVideoBelow.aspx)

Comment: I would up vote if I had the required reputation, plus I was looking for some thing that allowed me to have SetParameter files instead of bundling the Web.Config transforms in the Package. But having looked high and low myself I can see you are correct.

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted you question so you will get some points.